# Using jQuery .post method to send data to Django server but getting error 500?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm making a game that has a 10x10 board where if clicked upon, it will be marked with an "X". On one of my models I have an attribute that stores the values of each board cell and they are set to blank as default. I'm able to mark the board with jquery. However, I want to send data to the server side to let it know that the cell that I clicked on is marked. That way, when I quit the game and revisit it later, the board will show the marked cell with an "X".

This is my jquery code embedded in my HTML page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.target_cell').click(function(){ 
        if ($(this).text() != "X" && $(this).text() != "H"){
            $(this).text("X");
            var spot = $(this).attr('name'); //Cell index number like in an array
            $.post("/play_game/{{game.id}}/", spot);
        }
        else{
            alert("Spot already taken!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code for my view which is being accessed by my jquery .post method:

```
def play_game(request, game_id):
    game = fetch_game(request.user, game_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        spot = request.POST['spot']
        game.creator_target_board[int(spot)] = "X"
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'game': game,
        'set_board': game.creator_ship_board,
        'target_board': game.creator_target_board
    })
    return render_to_response('battleship/play_game.html', variables)
```

I'm currently using csrf_exempt on my view just for testing. When I click on my board cell, it gets marked with "X" but my server log shows a 500 error. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What does your urls.py look like?

I would recommend using ajax instead of post by doing the following:

in urls.py add:

```
url(r'^target_spot/(?P<game_id>\d+)/(?P<spot>\d+)/$', target_spot, name='target_spot'),
```

in your javascript call:

```
$.ajax("/target_spot/{{game.id}}/" + spot);
```

in your views add:

```
def target_spot(request, game_id, spot):
    if request.is_ajax():
        game = fetch_game(request.user, game_id)
        game.creator_target_board[int(spot)] = "X"
```

The advantage of this approach is that you're separating your logic, making your code cleaner, and its faster since the server isn't delivering a page upon every post request

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Currently, here is the part of my urls.py that does the mapping for the play_game view:     url(r'^$',main_page, name='main_page'),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page, name='user_page'),
    url(r'^create_game/$', create_game, name='create_game'),
    url(r'^play_game/(?P<game_id>\d+)/$', play_game, name='play_game'),

Comment: Regneel, I tried your approach. I'm getting a 500 error on my server log with this message: GET "/target_spot/1/0/ HTTP/1.1" 500

Comment: If you remove the is_ajax() check, you can go to the url (/target_spot/1/0) in your browser for a full django error report.

Comment: it says "unicode object does not support item assignment", here's the traceback link: http://dpaste.com/882866/

Comment: creator_target_board is a string, and strings are immutable in python. You should be using a dict.
    creator_target_board = {};
    creator_target_board[1] = "X"
Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)